# Complex number property

Tags: complex-geometry

> If the complex numbers 0, $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ are concyclic, prove that $\frac{1}{z_1}$,$\frac{1}{z_2}$,$\frac{1}{z_3}$ are collinear.

I really can't seem to get anywhere on this problem, but all I've deduced is that there might be some relationship between circle geometry properties and the arguments of the complex numbers. Is there a simple solution?

Comment: Cross post : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26894/complex-number-property

Comment: inversion in the unit circle maps the circle (0,$z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$) to a line

Comment: This is not "complex geometry".

Comment: But it is geometry of the complex plane...


Answer (score 1):

This can be seen using properties of Moebius transformations (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation )

A MT is a map of the extended complex numbers (so a point at infinity is added) of the form
$z$ maps to $(az+b)/(cz + d)$ where the matrix (a, b; c, d) is invertible.

Such a MT maps generalized circles to generalized circles (a generalized circle is a usual circle or a circle of 'infinite radius', a straight line and the point at infinity).

Now, you condider $z$ maps to $1/z$ which is a MT. Thus the image of your circle is a generalized circle; since $0$ is on the original circle, infinity is on the generalized circle you get. Thus, the other points are on a line.

PS: Next time please do not cross post here and on math stackexchange at the same time. For this type of question I suggest the other site.